# Add href to description in _config.yml

Tags: yaml, jekyll, minima

How can I add a link to [my](https://github.com/ogirginc/ogirginc.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml#L19) `description:` in `_config.yml`?

I tried using

```
 ...
 description: > # ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
   Ogulcan Girginc's personal <a href="www.example.com">homepage<a>.
 ...
```

and

```
 ...
 description: > # ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
   Ogulcan Girginc's personal [homepage](www.example.com).
 ...
```

but YAML (or Jekyll?) didn't render them.

Specs:

```
Jekyll: 3.2.1
Kramdown: 1.12
Theme: Minima
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do this in [footer.html](https://github.com/ogirginc/ogirginc.github.io/blob/master/_includes/footer.html):

```
<p>{{ site.description | escape }}</p>
```

If you want to render the HTML in the description, drop the `escape`.

Comment: Should have guessed `escape` returns an escaped version of html!